# Практически незаметное изменение толщины шрифта при наведении

Tags: html5, css3

При наведении почему-то меняется толщина шрифта. Почему так происходит?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond');

body {
    font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond';
    font-weight: 200;

}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-left: 1%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu h3 {
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #a87f5c;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: italic;
}
.menu h3 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a87f5c;
  font-size: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}
.menu h3 a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a87f5c;
}
.menu h3 a.selected {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a87f5c;
}
.menu .dropdown {
  height: 0;
}
.menu .dropdown h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #a87f5c;
  height: 30px;
}
.menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
  background-color: #a87f5c;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px 0 #a87f5c;
}
.menu .dropdown .dropdown_content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: -0.8em;
  width: 175px;
}
.menu .dropdown .dropdown_content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  transition: .6s all ease;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
  font-style: italic;
}
.menu .dropdown .dropdown_content a:hover {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 19px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="menu">
            <h3><a href="pages/main.html" class="selected">Главная</a></h3>
            
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <h3 href="pages/production.html" сlass="droplink">Продукция / портфолио</h3>
                    <div class="dropdown_content">
                        <a href="pages/tables.html">Столы</a>
                        <a href="pages/storage.html">Мебель для хранения</a>
                        <a href="pages/interior.html">Интерьер</a>
                </div>
        </div>
            <h3><a href="pages/contacts.html">Контакты</a></h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: в каком браузере смотрите? никаких изменений не вижу

Comment: в гугл хром. При наведении на ссылку "Продукция / портфолио" ссылки "Главная" и "Контакты" чуть заметно в течение где-то полсекунды чуть увеличивают толщину шрифта и потом возвращают первоначальное. Сделал шрифт 28px - если присмотреться, то дефект изменения толщины заметен.

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится, но обычно подобные проблемы решаются чем-то типа .dropdown, .dropdown_content { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden; }

Comment: Круто! Сработало! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    .dropdown, .dropdown_content { 
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
      backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Неплохая попытка, но мог хотя бы провести изыскательскую работу и выяснить какому из этих 2ух блоков таки надо поставить эти свойства, ибо я забыл.